# How to recursively traverse a binary search tree, appending each node to an ArrayList

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am writing a method to traverse a binary search tree recursively. It will visit every node and as it does so, append it to an ArrayList. So by the time all nodes are visited, they're going to be in the ArrayList.

I've written the following, but it's not working and I don't understand why.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

*Method as follows:*

```
/**
 * Traverse a Binary Search Tree and append each node to an ArrayList. 
 * 
 * @param n - this.root of the Binary Search Tree
 * @return - a ListArray of ALL nodes in the calling Binary Search Tree
 */
private List<TreeNode> traverse( TreeNode n ) {

    List<TreeNode> listOfNodes = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();

    if (n == null) 
        return listOfNodes;

    listOfNodes.add(n);

    traverse(n.left);
    traverse(n.right);

    return listOfNodes;

}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tired to debug a little example?

Comment: You never use the results of `traverse(n.left);` and `traverse(n.right);`.

Comment: @downvoters I don't quite get the downvotes. I don't think this question does not show any research effort, clearly the OP at least wrote some code (which is almost working). Yes, it is a trivial and beginner mistake, but one that is easily made by first-time users of recursions and if we would downvote everything on SO which is trivial or simple... well, we would downvote _a lot_.

Comment: and yes, it could be easily spotted using a debugger, but again this would apply to many questions on SO. Imho, one of the first things people should learn during programming courses is how to properly use a debugger... sadly, this is hardly ever part of any curriculum.

Answer (score 2):

In any case, you almost got the solution, but you do not use the result of your recursive calls. When you call `traverse(n.left)` and `traverse(n.right)` you should add the result of these calls to your `listOfNodes`